# How do you split by comma everything that is outside of brackets with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to separate a string by commas except what is inside square brackets

Example

```
Dog[Food, Toys], Cat[Movies, brush]
```

I want to get

```
"Dog[Food,Toys]","Cat[Movies,Brush]"]
```

Thanks

Comment: What attempts have you made to achieve this? Does it have to be with RegEx? In this example, I'd probably split the string into an array commas as the delimiter, then remove anything with a closing bracket, then split the remaining items into an array by the opening bracket and take the first element of each array.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Do you want to completely ignore anything in brackets (as in delete it), or do you want it to be part of Dog and Cat?

Comment: @KatharineOsborne Sorry, I need split only what is outside of brackets the response array I expect is
[
"Dog[Food,Toys]",
"Cat[Movies,Brush]"
]

Comment: For the OP's special use case a regex which just targets this special constellation by a [*positive lookbehind*](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) (and some optional whitespace) is totally sufficient ... [`'Dog[Food, Toys] , Cat[Movies, brush]'.split(/(?<=\])\s*,\s*/g)`](https://regex101.com/r/yhyMOw/1)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use below Regex to spilt the string. This regex finds any comma after closing square bracket.

> ,(?<=],)

[Test link](https://regex101.com/r/e8BX4m/1)

Comment: This won't work if there exists an item without brackets, e.g. `Dog, Cat[Movies, Brush], Horse[Stable]`

Answer (score 0):

A more reliable and also whitespace aware approach which especially takes *heothesennoc*'s comment on *Rajesh*'s solution ...

> *"This won't work if there exists an item without brackets, e.g. Dog, Cat[Movies, Brush], Horse[Stable] –
> heothesennoc"*

... into account has to feature a full lookaround, a [*negative lookbehind*](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) and a [*negative lookahead*](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#negative-lookahead).

The pattern would be as follows ... [(?<!\[[^\]]+)\s*,\s*(?!\])](https://regex101.com/r/yhyMOw/2). A description is provided with the link.

```js
// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/yhyMOw/2]
const regXSplit = /(?<!\[[^\]]+)\s*,\s*(?!\])/;

console.log([

  'Dog[Food, Toys], Fish,Cat[Movies, brush] ,Hamster[Litter, Food, Toys]',
  'Dog[Food, Toys],Bird, Cat[Movies, brush], Hamster[Litter, Food, Toys]',
  'Dog[Food, Toys],Mouse,Cat[Movies, brush] , Hamster[Litter, Food, Toys]',
  'Dog[Food, Toys] ,Horse, Cat[Movies, brush],Hamster[Litter, Food, Toys]',

].map(str => str.split(regXSplit)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice, so in plain English the regex translates to "Look for a comma, with or without whitespaces around it, that doesn't have a prefix that starts with `[` and is followed by one or more characters that are not `]`, and that doesn't have a suffix `]`. Love seeing these intricate regex expressions

Comment: And the reason for voting this answer -1 is of exactly which faulty technical nature? Providing at least a comment would do both, give the audience a correct answer, and give me the chance of improving my answer.